# ActiveRecord view generated SQL for single record methods

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

ActiveRecord allows you to see the SQL generated for a collection:

```
User.all.to_sql
```

How can I return the SQL generated for a method that returns a single record?

```
User.find(1).to_sql # not valid
User.print_sql.find(1) # something like this?
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_sql` method is defined in the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class, so you'd better use

```rb
User.where(id: 1).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 1"
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, let's turn to the Rails 6 source. Here is an excerpt from [ActiveRecord gem file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L157) `activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb`

```rb
def find(*ids) # :nodoc:
  # We don't have cache keys for this stuff yet
  return super unless ids.length == 1
  return super if block_given? ||
                  primary_key.nil? ||
                  scope_attributes? ||
                  columns_hash.key?(inheritance_column) && !base_class?

  id = ids.first

  return super if StatementCache.unsupported_value?(id)

  key = primary_key

  statement = cached_find_by_statement(key) { |params|
    where(key => params.bind).limit(1)
  }

  record = statement.execute([id], connection)&.first
  unless record
    raise RecordNotFound.new("Couldn't find #{name} with '#{key}'=#{id}", name, key, id)
  end
  record
end
```

One can clearly see that `find` method is expanded into `where(primary_key => id).limit(1)` and then result is taken from `first` element of returned `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection.

`find_by` method takes the same approach as one can see later in the same file.

Thus, `User.find(1)` and `User.where(id: 1).limit(1)` are semantically equivalent.

Comment: Do you think that `where` clause on primary key constraint can return multiple records? Then formulate your question more clearly.

Comment: My question is very clear. Please re-read. I gave your answer IN my question.

Comment: My original comment had a typo, sorry. I meant does not work for single record methods like `find_by`, but I accidentally wrote `find_all`

Comment: @LyzardKyng is correct. Except that with find, the sql has a limit added in

Answer (score 0):

`User.where(id: 1).limit(1).to_sql`

This is what is essentially what gets run in SQL when you use `find_by`.

The sql generated for a find query, ie `User.find(1)` is

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], 
["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: Now you'll get a minus too :)

Comment: Rails console shows the sql that is generated for a find request. Which is what I showed.